# Jquery or CSS Hover Over Image and display Image in Drupal Views

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, xhtml, drupal-7

Thanks for looking into this.

I have a Drual 7 webstie at the moment and i have views set up to display an image with some content underneath.

I cant seem to find anywhere where i can modify the layout of how views dispalys the content.

I need to be able to display a maginfying glass over an image when you hover over it. Each image and its content are displayed in a div class called .field-time.

I cant modify any html so i only have the drupal template and css to work with. I have added Jquery to do this but not sure about the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you could use css to do this.
I as far as I understand your looking to have a magnifying glass appear as the cursor whenever it hovers over `.field-time`

```
.field-time:hover {
    cursor: url(*path to image*), auto;
}
```

the path to image would then be a .gif or .png or something of the pointer you wish to use.
I'm not sure if this works on all browsers.

You can see more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url%28smiley.gif%29,url%28myBall.cur%29,auto)

Hope this helps

Comment: the ,auto; bit is important as it mean if you can't get url() then use default cursor.

Comment: Thank you for your input, thats helpful, although i didnt mean the cursor, i mean the whole image has a maginfying glass that pops up over it or fades in or something.

Comment: in that case you could probably use javascript/jquery. The event your looking for is .hover(), something like this $('.field-time').hover(function(){  //do something  });

Comment: Pretty much i want to be able to dispaly a magnifying glass over an image when i hover over it. cos it links to a lightbox image thing that pops up. 

does this seem right

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.field-item img').hover(function(){

 $('img').attr('style', 'border-style:solid;border-color:white; border-width:1px;');
});

});

Comment: i know thats only adding a boring by im just trying to control it at the moment before i do anythign else, i havent touched on Jquery for a while

Comment: yeah that's all there is to it, you just need to change it from being a border to being some sort of overlay image